# How can I solve a "JWT is not configured properly" issue?

Tags: wordpress, api, jwt

I try to connect my website with my WordPress API.
Backend and frontend are both on localhost.
Creating a user is working well but when I try to login, I get a

> JWT is not configured properly

error.

This is the error I have using Insomnia:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "statusCode": 403,
    "code": "jwt_auth_no_auth_header",
    "message": "Authorization header not found.",
    "data": []
}
```

[image: console-log jwt issue]

I have added this line of code on the auth plugin :

```php
            $auth = isset($allHeaders['AUTHORIZATION']) ?  $allHeaders['AUTHORIZATION'] : false;
```

I don't know where if the issue is on the back or front code.
And added `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1` on my .htaccess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the definition of JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY to the top of your wp-config.php file after the following:

```
(AUTH_KEY, SECURE_AUTH_KEY, ... NONCE_SALT)
```

The definition of JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY must be added before:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

This should resolve the bad config error.

Comment: The plugin editor should add this to the "docs"